# Tomcat session created for every request

Tags: java, session, tomcat, struts-1, struts-config

When I am trying to access `httprequest.getSession()` inside struts `DispatchAction,` it return new session. Any one know the reason for this problem?

The same problem does not occur when extending the `Action` struct.

Comment: Are you using struts1 ?! `DispatchAction` is not defined in Struts2

Comment: yes i am using struts1

Comment: Then please edit your question tag, and the only suggestion is update to struts2 the struts1 is end of life